# Spring-security session not available in java thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we are using Spring-security for authentication and authorization. There are some tasks where we would like to use a Thread, but whenever we are using a Java thread, and try to obtain details about authenticated user.

I also tried the `@Async` annotation, but it was not what we are looking as only specific parts of the code we need in a thread.

Is there any way to inject spring-session in a Java thread? If not, any alternative ways to run parts of code in a separate thread. Thank you.

Example code :

```
  public void sendNotification(Notification notification, int memberId) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Person onlinePerson = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
            GroupMembers groupMembers = this.groupMembersService.getMemberById(memberId);
}
thread.start();
}
```

Now, in the code above, if I try to get any information about onlinePerson, such as id with onlinePerson.getId();, I get an NPE. Check out the error log :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.spring.chat.ChatServiceImpl.lambda$sendNotification$3(ChatServiceImpl.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea how I can tackle this problem. Thank you.

Security-applicationContext.xml :

```
 <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http create-session="ifRequired" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username" password-parameter="j_password"
                             login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" default-target-url="/canvaslisting"
                             always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/denied"/>
        <security:remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me" user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
                              token-validity-seconds="1209600" data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
       <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https"/>-->
        <security:port-mappings>
            <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
        </security:port-mappings>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/" success-handler-ref="myLogoutHandler"/>

        <security:session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionReg" max-sessions="5" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <beans:bean id="sessionReg" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="jdbcTokenRepository"/>
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcTokenRepository"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl">
        <beans:property name="createTableOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Remember me ends here -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You can use `DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor` to pass SecurityContext to new threads. See [Spring Security 3.2 M1 Highlights, Servlet 3 API Support](http://spring.io/blog/2012/12/17/spring-security-3-2-m1-highlights-servlet-3-api-support/). You can also configure it in your implementation of `AsyncConfigurer` so that it works with `@Async` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the session information is stored in a `ThreadLocal` against the thread that handled the HTTP request.  It's not by default available to new threads (whether you create them manually or via `@Async`).

Fortunately this is easy to configure:

`SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)  //in a context loader listener for example`

Or with the environment variable:

`spring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question with Security-applicationContext.xml . Do you know where the above configuration goes in there?

Comment: I don't think it can go in there.  You either need a `ContextLoaderListener` for the first way to set it programatically or as a JVM option on startup: `-Dspring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL`

Comment: This worked nicely. As you can see I am also discussing this with another user. I am a bit confused with Runnable is often used to provide the code that a thread should run, but Runnable itself has nothing to do with threads. It's just an object with a run() method. Does this mean that the new Thread() I am creating is not a thread. Thank you.

Comment: I have to admit, I didn't look too closely at your code.  You are creating a new thread by extending the `Thread` class, while this works it's bad practise.  You should do this by implementing `Runnable`:  `Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {...}).start();`

Comment: When I do that, IntelliJ suggests me to create a new Lambda expression as follows `new Thread(()-> {//Thread code} )`. That's how I also used to create threads before Java8 came in.. :D

Comment: Ah!  I retract my previous statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Your thread class is not managed by spring, because in your code example you manually create the class instance by calling its constructor. You need to get your thread instance managed by spring and retrieve it from a bean using spring's `ApplicationContext`. I guess you want multiple thread instances running at the same time? If so, you may need a new thread-instance (bean) for each thread execution. Here is an example of how you can achieve this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype") // the scope “prototype" will return a new instance each time when the bean will be retrieved.
public class YourThreadClass implements Runnable {
   private String anyString;

   @Autowired
   AnyOtherBean anyOtherBean; // since YourThreadClass is now managed by spring, you can also inject services / components into YourThreadClass 
}

@Component
public class YourClassThatStartsTheThread{
   @Autowired
   ApplicationContext ctx;

   public void sendNotification(Notification notification, int memberId){
        // ... your code ....
        YourThreadClass aNewInstanceOfYourThreadClass = (YourThreadClass) ctx.getBean(YourThreadClass.class);
        // ... your code ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        sendNotification(notification, memberId);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new HelloThread()).start();
    }

}
```

`Runnable` is often used to provide the code that a thread should `run`, but `Runnable` itself has nothing to do with threads. It's just an object with a `run()` method.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Can you please elaborate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void sendNotification(Notification notification, int memberId) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                Person onlinePerson = this.personService.getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser();
                GroupMembers groupMembers = this.groupMembersService.getMemberById(memberId);
            }
        }
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: So, you mean the thread I am creating by new Thread() is not acutally a thread?

Comment: yes you dont have create thread and for your requests synchronize on new Object() and send